How to output html source code with google apps script?
Instead of outputting normal html in an apps script webapp, I'd like to output the actual source code of the html. Is there a way to do that?
If I right-click on the webapp output, I can't see the source code (or its difficult to get to). I'd rather just output it on the webapp, so that I can easily copy it.
Currently I'm just using this to output the content of a html template
function doGet(e) { var x = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html_template"); return x.evaluate(); }
The html_template is more complex, but basically it just output some data from a google sheet. I realise that I can just convert any "<" and ">" parts of the html tags to < and > to get the desired source code output, but surely there must be a more elegant way?

Okay, I figured it out. Pretty simple.
All I needed to do was to an xmp tag before and after my content.
<xmp><my html content></xmp>

